# How to implement "mouse resistance" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to implement mouse resistance in JavaScript.

As an example of what I mean, think of how the Enlightenment window manager handles screen edge resistance to switch between different desktops, or if you are not familiar with that:

Imagine a large rectangle with a square within it.
When click-moving the mouse [`onmousedown`] within the square, the mouse lets itself be moved until the borders of the square, then exercises some resistance until a threshold is met, and then moves around within the larger rectangle.

Ideally the mouse cursor should stay trapped within the square until that threshold isn't met, and only leave that area if it is met.

Any ideas or examples of this somewhere?
A cross-browser solution is also greatly appreciated. (Down to IE7, that is)

Comment: You can't influence the mouse position with javascript so that's not an option. With flash you are able to hide the cursor though, that might give you some possibility of what you want.

Comment: Thats what crossed my mind as well, but i was hoping i was wrong.

Is there any other way you can think of [ui wise] to achieve the same effect?

Comment: @WoLpH: Was about to mention that. However, I don't think hiding the mouse is a good idea - the best you can do is to create the *illusion* of the mouse changing position, and when the user moves out of the affected area there will be a disjoint in the position of the fake and real cursor that can confuse or annoy. It's not a problem when you're talking about OS level implementation though.

Comment: @Yi Jiang, when the user overcomes the threshold and the mouse exits the affected area, the real mouse pointer can be unhid and the user can now see where it really is. I don't think the snap would be confusing or annoying, as long as the threshold's not unreasonably large. The user can expect it due to the resistance effect. @user436118, you should be able to hide the cursor w/o Flash, using a custom cursor for the CSS _cursor_ property: `cursor: url(mycursor.cur)` where mycursor.cur is a blank cursor.

Comment: But what is this for? Is this for dragging components within a container? Is it for hovering over clickable items? Surely, the mouse pointer has a target and you can better advice on alternative approaches is you explain what that target is and what it is that you're exactly trying to achieve.

Comment: @ates: the usecases are quite a few.. for instance, dragging stuff in a container and warning the user that something is not proper, or when he drags stuff out of a container, or ... dozens of usecases apply.
In my specific case its a bunch of dragbars which may only be dragged to a specific position and the user needs to be informed that there is a "bump" at that position [think something like alignment marks, but not really that]. 
Anyhow i think i'll investigate the cursor: url apprach, and perhaps play around with that a bit.

Comment: You can't change mouse position, but how about just having the object lag behind the cursor a bit when it's dragged over that particular spot? Then when you've reached the threshold, it can snap back to the cursor position. I think you'll get less headaches than trying to mess with the user's cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated you can't set the mouse position with Javascript.

Since you asked about implementing this on `mousedown`, however, I assume the user is dragging something around on screen. So you could have the element they are dragging show this behavior. You need two elements to act as regions, one where the target can be freely dragged and another to define the size of the boundary. I'd do it with jQuery to shorten up the code but basically you'd have something like this. (Untested code)

HTML:

```
<div class='borderLand'>
    <div class='freeZone'>
        <img class='draggable'>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.borderLand {position: relative; width: 110px; height: 110px;}
.freeZone {position: relative; top: 10px; left:10px; height: 100px; width: 100px;}
```

JS:

I can't write the full code off the top of my head but the algorithm would be something like

```
onmousedown{
  check for click location
  if it's over the draggable (watch for bubbling) begin dragging, set dragging flag
}

onmouseup{
  clear dragging flag if it's set
}

borderland onmouseover{
  if dragging, stop the movement of the draggable (watch for bubbling here too)
}

borderland onmouseout{
  start dragging again (if they move back in or out it doesn't matter, you want to drag)
}
```

Sorry if you need more detail, but doing this in plain JS would be a little lengthy and I'm not sure how much help you need.